# Chrome is ignoring correct css spec for animation

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a bunch of CSS animation properties declared individually on elements. As far as I can see, they are all declared properly. The animation is also working fine, but when I look in Chrome Developer tools, I can see lots of yellow exclamation markers next to the non-prefixed spec versions of the properties. See image below:

[image]

I think the yellow marker means the property and value were ignored because they were specified improperly. So why is it doing that here?

Comment: @Pete no the dashes are there, you just can't see them because Chrome  has put a line through them

Comment: ah ok, if you are using a chrome browser before 39 it only understands the webkit version of animation properties so it will interpret non prefixed properties as unknown properties which is why you get the yellow exclamation.  If you hover over the exclamation mark it usually tells you what the error is.  See lower graph on this page: http://caniuse.com/#search=animation

Comment: @Pete Your link is to the incorrect Can I Use page. Also, I know it is ignoring the other prefixes because it only accepts -webkit- for animations in Chrome. But it grays out the -moz- and -o- versions because they are 'unknown property names' but it puts a yellow marker next to the spec version because it has an 'invalid property value'. So it recognises the property but says it's invalid. What I'm trying to understand is what is invalid about it? It's not just the browser saying 'I don't need that vendor prefix' so it's unrecognised. It's actually saying it's been written in an invalid way.

Comment: It is invalid because chrome ONLY uses the webkit version for css 3 animations (which is the second part of the can i use page I linked to) so the unprefixed version is an unknown property to chrome.  Chrome also only greys out the other prefixed versions as it is clever enough to know that they are prefixed for other browsers

Comment: Ah right! That was the differentiation I was looking for. Didn't realise Chrome understood prefixed versions or anything but not the spec versions.